# Jquery clone a div giving new ids from a hidden div and show new divs

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to clone a hidden div and showing the new divs created with new ids. This seems to do the job...

`var newElem = $('#input1').clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum).removeClass('clonedInput').addClass('ShowClones');`

But the div stops creating new ids after the first new div is created. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrienboufflet/7kkaLnh3/2/). When setting the original class back to block and removing:

`.removeClass('clonedInput').addClass('ShowClones');`

The cloning goes back to normal and creates divs with new ids?

Comment: The following code will fix your delete button, but you need to change quite a lot of code with add button, because the ids aren't unique after you have cloned those items. Perhaps it would be easier to create new table with items and unique ids. The code:            $('#btnDel').click(function () {

                $('.ShowClones').last().remove();

                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
                
                var num = $('.ShowClones').length;
      
                if (num == 1)

                    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            });

Comment: Your `newNum` is reset to the same value on each click. This value `var num =  ('.clonedInput').length; var newNum = num + 1;` never changes.

Comment: yes i actually just realised this whas my problem ;-). I would need to call the ('.ShowClones') instead of ('.clonedInput') then i guess?

Comment: not sure how to count the .length of the new class now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example for those who are interested

http://jsfiddle.net/adrienboufflet/7kkaLnh3/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btnAdd').click(function () {

                var num = $('.datatable_class').length; 

                var newNum = num + 1; 


                var newElem = $('#input1').clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum).removeClass('clonedInput').addClass('.ShowClones');


//row1
                newElem.find('#td02 input').attr('id', 'num02_' + newNum).attr('name', 'num02_' + newNum).val('');
                newElem.find('#td03 input').attr('id', 'idfixture03_' + newNum).attr('name', 'idfixture03_' + newNum).val('');

//row2      
                newElem.find('#td21 input').attr('id', 'num21_' + newNum).attr('name', 'num21_' + newNum).val('');
                newElem.find('#td22 input').attr('id', 'idfixture22_' + newNum).attr('name', 'idfixture22_' + newNum).val('');

//row3   
                newElem.find('#td31 input').attr('id', 'num31_' + newNum).attr('name', 'num31_' + newNum).val('');
                newElem.find('#td32 input').attr('id', 'idfixture32_' + newNum).attr('name', 'idfixture32_' + newNum).val('');

//row4                
                newElem.find('#td41 input').attr('id', 'num41_' + newNum).attr('name', 'num41_' + newNum).val('');
                newElem.find('#td42 input').attr('id', 'idfixture42_' + newNum).attr('name', 'idfixture42_' + newNum).val('');

                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

                if (newNum == 100)

                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            });

            $('#btnDel').click(function () {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
                $('#input' + num).remove();

                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);

                if (num - 1 == 1)

                    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your elements so that you attach your clones to one container then your count will accurately reflect your clone count;

```
<div id="results"><!-- I am empty --></div>

var n = $("#results").children().length;  // 0
var id = "input" + n;
var clone = $("#clonedInput").clone().attr("id", id);
clone.appendTo("#results");

// $("#results").children().length // 1
<div id="results"><input id="input0" ... /></div>
```

Comment: thanks for that one. can't seem to get it working though. did you mean appendTo and not attachTo?  What happens now is that on page load, the div input1 is loaded and hidden beacause of its class. but onclick, the div is removed? and no new div is created

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/adrienboufflet/7kkaLnh3/5/) here is the working example if interested. I actually just created a class for the table inside the div and counted that class instead of the div class.  The new divs now have a +1 id and so do the elements inside the div.